# App crashed after starting an intent using a android on click method

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-emulator

i have an android on click function that that starts a intent using the method startActivaty()
when I executed the function the app crashed over and over again. here is the error code `04-18 23:15:09.012 23801-23801/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority , priority [3] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SHV-E210S_4.4.4_0028
04-18 23:15:09.012 23801-23801/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> Normal User
04-18 23:15:09.012 23801-23801/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> com.example.user.multiplication [ userId:0 | appId:10167 ]
04-18 23:15:09.012 23801-23801/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-18 23:15:09.162 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
04-18 23:15:09.162 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
04-18 23:15:09.162 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 18817: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
04-18 23:15:09.162 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
04-18 23:15:09.162 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
04-18 23:15:09.162 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 18821: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
04-18 23:15:09.162 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
04-18 23:15:09.192 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication D/MultiPhoneWindow: generateLayout : sMinimumStackBoundForPortraitOrientRect(0, 0 - 0, 0), sMinimumStackBoundForLandscapeOrient=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)
04-18 23:15:09.212 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
04-18 23:15:09.212 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 415: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
04-18 23:15:09.212 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-18 23:15:09.212 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
04-18 23:15:09.212 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 437: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
04-18 23:15:09.212 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-18 23:15:09.257 23801-23833/com.example.user.multiplication V/MediaPlayer: decode(53, 390064, 113425)
04-18 23:15:09.257 23801-23831/com.example.user.multiplication V/MediaPlayer: decode(52, 315460, 74558)
04-18 23:15:09.332 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
04-18 23:15:09.337 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
04-18 23:15:09.342 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
04-18 23:15:09.402 23801-23801/com.example.user.multiplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0`
 I didn't understand the code. please help

Answer (score 1):

Please provide your source code from your main activity and main layout to get a better answer (and possibly even a fix!).

But for what I can check in the log you are trying to invoke a method (maybe from the layout file) that you are not providing implementation for in your classes (most likely in your main activity). Based on:

```
Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
```